# Diffeomorphism and determinant of Jacobian

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

I don't remember where I read it and if I remember it correctly but does the following hold true?

If $M,N$ are two (smooth?) surfaces and $f: M \to N$ is a homeomorphism such that $det(J_f)$ (the determinant of the Jacobian of $f$) has constant sign then $f$ is a diffeomorphism

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the Jacobian of $f$ has constant sign that means it is nonzero at each point. Therefore, the inverse function theorem applies and you obtain a local inverse at each point, and that restricted function is a local diffeomorphism. If this was all we had then it would not be enough because local injectivity need not imply global injectivity. However, you also have that $f$ is a homeomorphism thus $f$ is a continuous bijection with continuous inverse. I believe this means we can weave together the local diffeomorphisms to form a global diffeomorphism.

Comment: I think you're done after you cite that $f$ is a homeomorphism; it's an injective local diffeo, hence a diffeo.

Comment: How do you weave them together?

Comment: @Neal I agree, the fact we have that $f$ is a bijection which is locally a diffeomorphism suffices. We check smoothness of $f$ locally so the only question that remains to prove global diffeomorphism is the existence of a global inverse. The inverse of $f$ exists by assumption if $f$ is a homeomorphism (and hence a bijection)

Comment: @snailspace the fact that the local inverses weave (or paste, glue pick your favorite word here) together is a necessary consequence of the given injectivity of $f$. Suppose you find a local inverse on $U$ and another on $V$ then $f|_U$ and $f|_V$ are invertible and the we can argue that $f|_{U \cup V}$ is also invertible because, if it wasn't that contradicts the given injectivity of $f$. Moreover, $f|_{U \cup V}$ has smooth inverse by application of the inverse function theorem on each piece.